# PHP - Splitting stylesheet into arrays

Tags: php, css, arrays, stylesheet

I would like to split stylesheet into arrays in a way that every selector is in separeted array with his style. I have this code so far and it is working good, but not in situations where there are media queries. What I would like to achieve is that I split selectors inside media query into single arrays but that each of them has his media query selector as well.
This is example of style in HTML

```
<style>
#abc{ background-color: gray; font-size: 10px;}
.abc { background-color: gray; font-size: 10px;}

@media only screen and (max-width:640px) {
  #abc {
    height: 200px !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:640px) {
  #abcd {
    height: 200px !important;
  }
    .abcd {
    height: 200px !important;
  }
}
</style>
```

This is code I have so far:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$para = $dom->getElementsByTagName('style'); #DOMNodeList
if ($para instanceof DOMNodeList) {
    foreach ($para as $node) {
        printf ($node->nodeValue);
}
}
$file = $node->nodeValue;

$arrs = explode('}', $file);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrs); $i++)
{
    echo 'style ' . $i . ' - ' . $arrs[$i] . '<br />';
}
```

This is uotput I'm getting:

```
style 0 - #abc{ background-color: gray; font-size: 10px;
style 1 - .abc { background-color: gray; font-size: 10px;
style 2 - @media only screen and (max-width:640px) { #abc { height: 200px !important; 
style 3 - 
style 4 - @media only screen and (max-width:640px) { #abcd { height: 200px !important; 
style 5 - .abcd { height: 200px !important;
```

Wanted output:

```
style 0 - #abc{ background-color: gray; font-size: 10px;
style 1 - .abc { background-color: gray; font-size: 10px;
style 2 - @media only screen and (max-width:640px) { #abc { height: 200px !important; 
style 3 - 
style 4 - @media only screen and (max-width:640px) { #abcd { height: 200px !important; 
style 5 -  @media only screen and (max-width:640px) { .abcd { height: 200px !important;
```

What would be proper way to get that?

Comment: `if ($para instanceof DOMNodeList) {`: this test is useless, `$para` is always a `DOMNodeList` instance even if there isn't any `style` tag. Why using `printf ($node->nodeValue);`? Write `echo $node->nodeValue;`, there's nothing to format.

Comment: To answer your main question, the proper way is propably to find a css parser library: http://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte , I tried, but that parser doesn't support media queries. It is an opened issue still

Comment: In this case take a look at this fork: https://github.com/yunosh/PHP-CSS-Parser

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, just keep in mind that this answer requires that you know or make sure that media queries are the last part of the stylesheet and that there are no other styles declared between one media and another, following the format of your example. Then you could do something like this:

```
...
$file = $node->nodeValue;
$parts = explode('@media', $file);


// The first part of the stylesheet, where there are no media queries
$styleCount = 0;
$arrs = explode('}', $parts[0]);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrs); $i++)
{
    echo 'style ' . $i . ' - ' . $arrs[$i] . '<br />';
    $styleCount++;
}

// The media queries, remember to validate that there exists at least one before
for ($i = 1; $i < count($parts); $i++){
    $arrs = explode('{', $parts[$i], 2);
    $title = "@media " . $arrs[0];

    $arrIn = explode('}', $arrs[1]);
    for($j = 0; $j < count($arrIn); $j++){
        // Validate for an empty space or a new line, it could be just something like strlen($arrIn[$j]) > 3
        if(strlen($arrIn[$j]) > 4){
            echo 'style ' . $styleCount . ' - ' . $title . " { " . $arrIn[$j] . '</br>';
            $styleCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the output I'm getting:



     style 1 - .abc { background-color: gray; font-size: 10px;
     style 2 - 
     style 3 - @ media only screen and (max-width:640px) { 
     style 4 - @ media only screen and (max-width:640px) { 
     style 5 - @ media only screen and (max-width:640px) { 
     style 6 - @ media only screen and (max-width:640px) { 
     style 7 - @ media only screen and (max-width:640px) { 
     style 8 - @ media only screen and (max-width:640px) { 
     style 9 - @ media only screen and (max-width:640px) {

Comment: Sorry try my edited answer, I made some corrections, like using `$arrIn[$j]` instead of $i

Comment: The only change in the output would be that the empty style would be #2 instead of #3:
`style 0 - #abc{ background-color: gray; font-size: 10px;
style 1 - .abc { background-color: gray; font-size: 10px;
style 2 - 
style 3 - @media only screen and (max-width:640px) { #abc { height: 200px !important; 
style 4 - @media only screen and (max-width:640px) { #abcd { height: 200px !important; 
style 5 - @media only screen and (max-width:640px) { .abcd { height: 200px !important; `